# Better approach to find a data from ADO.NET source in DFT in SSIS 2008

Tags: ssis

I have a DFT and I have defined a ADO.NET Source and an ADO.NET Destination.
I need to find the maximum of a datetime column from ADO.NET source.

Currently I am using aggregate transformation which has two outputs one with maxdatetime and the other one with all columns in group by to get all the rows in the other output.
MaxDatetime -Maximum Date time from column
AllRows  -All rows(defining all columns in the group by )

Is there any better way to do this.

I dont want a group by for the ADO.NET source as its a slow operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done similar follow up on the MS forum and got this answer. Hope I can post the link here.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/8d02957e-becb-440a-9eba-9540b620b617

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use an execute SQL task, Select Max(datetimeColumn) from tablename and store the result in a variable.

Comment: My queries are configurable and I dont want to reconfigure/create new config entries into  it again to find the max date also [unhappy] . And moreover,I need to operate on the same result set got from  my ADO.NET SQL Select operation,as another Execute SQL statement task can produce another resultset(Consider some new records coming to that table at the time of execute SQL task).

Comment: Update: The Aggregate transformation component is causing memory issue.So looking for other methods